# How can i make a Fa object clickable?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I've read other questions before and the best answer I saw was to wrap it in an anchor tag. like

```
<a href="account.php"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
```

but that doesn't work. My fa object turns blue so it works as a anchor object but I can't click it.

I can't find out why it isn't working. I thought maybe something with my html?

Here is my code:

```
                <html>
            <head>
            <title>'.$title.'</title>           
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />
            <link href="core/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            </head>
            <body>  
            <header id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1><i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:36px"></i>DataBaas</h1>
                </div>
                   <div class="box" onclick="alert("You clicked me !")">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:36px"></i>
                  </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="article">
                    '.$content().'
                <div>
            </div>
            </body>     
            </html>
```

I want the fa-user to be clickable and link to a other page. I tried onclick as you see in my code to check if that was working but that also won't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/cvvcxbnh/

Comment: how it doesn't work with anchor , look here https://jsfiddle.net/tv0gas4v/

Comment: An anchor tag is not clickable if you dont add href attribute

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق already tried that but doesnt work to me. thats why i tried to ask here. i think my html is blocking it for some reason. i will edit my script. could you take a look?

Comment: have your heard about CSS? it might be helpful in this case

Comment: @dfsq i linked it already

Comment: have you looked at the fiddle?

Comment: anyway, you just need to wrap it in `a` (target blank), not clear what is the problem

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرقat the moment its wraped in a "a" like your fiddle but it isnt working. i linked my css below.

Comment: yes I tried it a css problem, I'm looking

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق its a css proble, when i remove al the css it works

Comment: @TimoVerberne I've added details on my answer

Comment: Please do not modify your question to turn it into an answer; I have rolled that edit back. Questions should be (mostly) preserved as they were originally asked, so there is a reasonable continuation between the genuine problem you had and the answer you received. Modifying the question breaks that continuation and makes the resulting page much less helpful for future readers. If you have further detail you would like to offer, please as it as a self-answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add position relative to box div

that's caused by absolute positioning of container, however adding z-index solves the problem but z-index works only on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  background-color: #f6f9fc;
}
#header {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #888888;
}
p {
 font-family: Arial;
}
#header h1 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  color: #3c8be4;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header .container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.article {
  margin: 100px 15%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: animation1;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
header .box {
  float: right;
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 33px;
  margin-right: 33px;
  color: #4e4e4e;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor:pointer;  
  z-index: 2;
}
.article h1{
  color: #4e4e4e;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.article p{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #535353;
  display: inline-block;
}
.login h1{
 font-size: 2rem;
}
.login {
 float: right;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #888888;
 width: 300px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 15px;
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.inlogform {
  margin-top: 40px;
} 
.login h3,h4 {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 0.8rem;
   line-height: 0;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.login h4{
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: red;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0;
}
input[type=password] {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 0px solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: 3c8be4;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
@keyframes animation1 {
    0%   {margin:0px 15%;opacity: 0;} 
    100%   {margin: 100px 15%; opacity: 1;}
} 
}

/*Mobiele Weergave*/
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  #header .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #header {
   height: 80px;
  }
  #header h1 {
 font-size: 30px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 5%;
  }
  .content {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.article{
    margin: 60px 5%;
}
.register {
        margin-left: 5%;
}
#header .box {
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-right: 22px;
}
.login {
 float:left;
}
@keyframes animation1 {
    0%   {margin:0px 5%;opacity: 0;} 
    100%   {margin: 60px 5%; opacity: 1;}
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <header id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1><i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:36px"></i>DataBaas</h1>
                </div>
                   <div class="box" >
                  <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
                  </div>
            </header>
            
            <div class="content">
                <div class="article">
                    '.$content().'
                <div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here  you should add "href" value inside "a" tag. And in order to open to other page just use target="_blank" inside "a" tag.Hope it will work.

```
   <div class="container">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:36px"></i>DataBaas</h1>
     </div>
   <div class="box">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:36px; 
   color:black;"></i></a>
     </div>
```

Comment: ".header container" postion is the problem

Comment: what do you mean by header container?